# Best Approach: qgis on mysql or reverse geocoding

Tags: mysql, geospatial, reverse-geocoding, qgis

i need to find out what is the best method for what i'm looking.
Basically, based on user position (lat and lng coords.), i need to find their corresponding city..

my first attempt was gmaps (reverse geocoding):

**Pros:**
easy to use

**Cons:**
use is limited to N requests
according to their policies, using reverse geocoding without any visual in frontend is prohibited.
Each country has their own typography ( there is no standart field to obtain):

my second scenario, was mysql geospational:
After download gadm shape files, i tried to convert them para mysql using shp2mysql but no success..

**Pros:**
there is no need any external service to retrieve city

**My Cons:**
Unable to use them correctly.

So, am i on a right way? is second approach better than one? i only need cities/countries based on a user location, nothing more..

Any sugestion or maybe a good tutorial?

After hours:

CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY NOT NULL, SPATIAL INDEX(g)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

Next:

```
C:\Program Files\FWTools2.4.7>ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:dbname,user=root
,password=root C:\shape_pt\PRT_adm1.shp -nln geom -update -overwrite -lco GEOMET
RY_NAME=g
ERROR 1: MySQL error message:The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes
Description: ALTER TABLE `geom` ADD SPATIAL INDEX(`g`)
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer PRT_adm1 (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: well, as the second option doesn't seem to work, it is a no-brainer: you can't use that one....

Comment: sure, but is it possible to avoid reverse geocoding using option two?

Comment: Finding a location from a name (like a street, city) is geocoding, right? Well, if you want to find a name from a location, that is the definition of 'reverse geocoding' I believe. So you goal is reverse geocoding: then I don't understand how any method to achieve that would eliminate the need to.. well.. do that :)

Comment: well, you're missing the point. sure, it's definitly reverse geocoding. there is no doubt about it.
The attempt here, is avoid google services

Comment: [Reverse Geocoding using MySQL GIS](http://gtowey.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/reverse-geocoding-using-mysql-gis.html).

Comment: Will "nearest postcode" work for you?  If so, you probably can find a postcode table for your country.

Comment: all tentatives to import shape files into mysql failed.. any suggestion? i'm using windows 7. i think the best way is really use gis, but no success at all, converting shape files to .sql